# My Blog-Site is generated dynamically per Ajax; the content is not searchable

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html, browser-history

My Blog-Site is generated dynamically per Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and HTML History API.  Problem is: my content is not searchable. 
Googlebot  render my site and i have read that google is now analytics such sites. What can i do, that my content is searchable?

I found similar questions but not a answer.

Comment: design it by another way is good way for you. AJAX and HTML History API is not good idea for blog. But if you really want to use these technologies you can implement detecting bots and sending them another HTML content. This is technically possible but it is not good idea.

Comment: @Misaz that is garbage. Single page apps can be indexed properly if set up properly

Comment: Google `site:http://www.jbi-weisendorf.de/` you'll see that it is indexed, but since I don't understand German(?) I don't know if it indexed the content of the page or just the basic template

Comment: Alan Eitan, i know that - but not my blog, only my static sites

Comment: Misaz and Charlietft; i need only answers for my question and im searching for a solution, i like this way!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: why, you are changing my question?

Comment: @jbiWeisendorf: See the edit comment: I removed irrelevant material. Your question cannot rely on off-site information, and is self-contained without the link, so I removed the link which otherwise looks like linkbait (which I figured probably was not the goal). I also removed the "Thanks for your help! Jürgen Bierlein" because that's just not how SO works (whether that's good or not is not up to me).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: for me my link is necessary, because if someone see my work he can better unterstand what i have done.

This ist not the help, that i need :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i generate static html-files from my dynamic content - this is termporarly my solution

Thanks, for your **great** help

Jürgen

Comment: Meanwhile, I have a keyword search realized. In the search you will get a keyword list to your initial letters and after selecting the appropriate articles.